# intermittent 500 error coming from node.js websocket server

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache

I have a websocket node.js app (game server) that runs a multiplayer html5 game.

The game has a website also. The game server and the website are on the same Apache VPS.

The game server uses mysql to store and retrieve data using mysql pooling from the node.js mysql package.

It works fine 99% of the time, but intermittently, at a random point, it will all of a sudden stop being able to get a mysql connection.

When this happens the website stops working and shows a 500 http error. I believe that this is whats causing the problem in the game server. Because of the 500 http error, mysql can no longer be connected to and thus pool.getConnection no longer works in the game server.

I find it strange that even though Apache is throwing up a 500 error, the game server can still be accessed successfully through a websocket as usual. The only thing that appears to have stopped working inside the game server is mysql. The game client connects to the game server via websocket and the functions work correctly, except for being able to connect to mysql.

If I ctrl+c the game server to stop the node.js app (game server) then the 500 error goes away. The website instantly serves up again, and then if I restarting the game server, mysql is now working again.

Obviously something in the game server is causing this to happen. So far i cannot find what it is. I am stuck now, i've spent a full week trying everything i could think of to debug this.

After running debug mode on mysql, im seeing this;

```
<-- ErrorPacket
ErrorPacket {
fieldCount: 255,
errno: 1203,
sqlStateMarker: '#',
sqlState: '42000',
message: 'User (i've hidden this) already has more than 
\'max_user_connections\' 
active connections' }
```

But I have it set to 100000 connections. No way is there that many being used. Every time I finish with a connection I use connection.release() to put it back into the pool. What do I need to do to fix this?

Please, any suggestion you have to debug this is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

here is the way i'm using mysql in the game server

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 100000,
        host     : '***********',
        user     : '***********',
        password : "'***********",
        database : '***********',
        debug    :  true
});


pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }   

    connection.query("select * from aTable  ",function(err,rows){

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            connection.release();
            return false;

        }

        // dos stuff here

        connection.release();
    })

})
```

1 thing i am wondering, if there is an error in the top error catch block
here ->

```
 pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }
```

Then the connection is not released right? So that would keep a connection alive and this is whats causing the problem? over time an error happens here and there, after a random amount of time, enough of these happen and that's what is causing it? it's like a build up of open connections???

Comment: I think we should see the code to know more but the error message makes me think the problem is probably due to a failure in the way to connect and disconnect.

Comment: @VirgilioGM i jave added a code snippet and a little extra info, please take a look.

Comment: As you say, if there was an error in `pool.getConnection()` the connection would remain open so you should also include `connection.release()`. Anyway, do you check the logs and have you seen any errors printed or not?

Comment: @VirgilioGM I had originally included the connection release into each of those if blocks like so ` pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){

       if (err) {
            console.log(err); connection.release();
            return false;
        } `    however, occasionally the app was crashing, saying that the connection was already released, by removing it from that block solved that problem. Also, yes i do check my logs, i have it set to create an individual log for each user as a text file in a folder on my server, yes i do have a few errors that are happening.

Comment: @VirgilioGM  I'm about to make another SO for a particular bizarre error and i will post the link here give me 5 minutes please :-).... in a nutshell, i'm checking to see if a unique field in a row exists, i'm being returned zero rows (it doesn't exist) then i try to insert the new row but then get told that it does exists and an error is thrown because its a duplicate key.

Comment: @VirgilioGM Can i just clarify...... Should i now go through and add connection.release to every if block as mentioned above? from if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }  to if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            connnection.release(); return false;
        } ???

Comment: Yes, I think you should add `connection.release()` to every `if (err)` block. Is it possible that when you get the "connection already released" error it was caused by a missing return statement? If all of these blocks end with a return statement, it's not possible for the code to continue and execute another `connection.release()`.

Comment: @VirgilioGM sadly i have run out of time right now... i will be back in roughly 3 hours.. i hope you may still be here to help then :-)

Comment: @VirgilioGM I had fixed this the other day but forgot to update this... Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

This was the mistake i was making;

```
pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }   

    connection.query("select * from aTable  ",function(err,rows){

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            connection.release();
            return false;

        }

        if(somethingrelevant){

            // do stuff

            connection.release();

        }

    })

})
```

And that meant that if somethingrelevant didn't happen, then the connection would stay open. 
My pool would continue to open new connections but they weren't always being put back.